# How to add click Listener in imageView that in GridView?

Tags: java, android

I am new here, and I developing simple Gallery App in Android, so I am facing some errors, then I want to share it with you.
My App contains **GridView** with **custom layout** and **Adapter**, and Custom layout Contains **Two imageViews**, one is image is the ***Main image*** and the other is ***Favourite icon***.the **GridView** has `setOnItemClickListener` method that goes another `Activity`, but i want to add `onCLick` method on ***Favourite ImageView***

[image: Here is a Screenshot Image]

**When I run the App, I got this error:**

```
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick
```

**custom_layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/xik_1"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/favicon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:onClick="onClickViaMain"

    />
```

**GridAdapter.java**

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private int icons[];

// my images here
public int images[]={R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.xik_2,R.drawable.xik_3
        ,R.drawable.xik_1,R.drawable.xik_11,R.drawable.xik_12};

private Context context;
private String letters[];
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public GridAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
    this.letters=letters;
    this.images=images;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View gridView=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        // LayoutInflater
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // my custom layout
        gridView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);
    }

    // images on the gridView (Android icon)
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

    return gridView;
}
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GridView gridView;
GridAdapter gridAdapter;
ImageView fav;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    gridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    // Adapter class
    gridAdapter=new GridAdapter(MainActivity.this);

    //initializing favourite icon
    fav=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.favicon);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    gridView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

    // gridView setting click listener
    //goes another Activity
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SliderActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index",position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



}

public void onClickViaMain(View v){
    if (fav.isPressed()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added to Favourites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Now, I want to do **onClick** on this **Image View(Favourite)** in **MainActivity**, what would you suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I got your requirement, follow the steps here

```
1. remove  android:onClick="onClickViaMain" from favicon imageView to avoid crash from xml layout

2. MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
           // handle click  
      }            

// other code 
} 


3. public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
// other code 
View.OnClickListener listener;
public GridAdapter(Context context,View.OnClickListener listener){

    this.listener=listener;
    this.context=context;
    this.letters=letters;
    this.images=images;
}
// other code here

Inside getView Method of your Adapter do like below 

    // images on the gridView (Android icon)
    ImageView favicon=(ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.favicon);

    favicon.setImageResource(images[position]);
    **favicon.setOnClickListener(listener);**



4. In Main Activity update line 

    gridAdapter=new GridAdapter(MainActivity.this);

    gridAdapter=new GridAdapter(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this);


// because we implemented OnclickListener in MainActivity  and we are done
```

Comment: I tried this, it works, but not fine, i want to interact with database and other functionality in the main Activity.

Comment: so you need image click inside activity?

Comment: yes broH, ineed inside main Activity, to interact with many functions

Comment: follow the steps in answer , I am adding steps one by one there

Comment: let me know if still facing the issue

Comment: you got it, Thanks for your answer and your effort. Again Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        ImageView favImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.favImage);
        favImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do your code
                Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SliderActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("index",position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
});
```

You can achieve image click on activity like this.
Hope this will help you...If you still face any issue please let me know.

Comment: You did it, but there is one problem, I want when the user click the Main image, the another Activity will be open, but if the user clicked the favicon image to do something. WORKS FINE , but for the first time the app launched , i click the favicon image , it will hover the main image and then automatically goes another activity, when i go back MainAcity then i click the favicon works fine. thants is problem. could you fix it please? thatnks for your time.

Comment: remove this first " android:onClick="onClickViaMain" from your layout file which u have set in adapter

Comment: @Farkhan What is exact issue? i given code as example that how you can make clicklistener for your gridview items.Now which issue you are facing?

Comment: i already did it, everything is working fine, but the FIrst time to launch the App, i want to seperate click for each (Main-Image and Favourite).

Comment: @Farkhan ok got it you can manage one boolean flag for check first launch or not and make two diffrent click listeners for those task.. got it? ..if this answer help you than please upvote it and accept it so other can also use same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is
remove onItemClick method from MainActivity and implement onClick method for image view in your GridAdapter

look like

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private int icons[];

// my images here
public int images[] =
        {R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.xik_2,
                R.drawable.xik_3, R.drawable.xik_1, R.drawable.xik_11, R.drawable.xik_12};

private Context context;
private String letters[];
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public GridAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.letters = letters;
    this.images = images;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View gridView = convertView;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // my custom layout
    gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    // images on the gridView (Android icon)
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ImageView favImage=(ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.favicon);

    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
    favImage.setImageResource(images[position]);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SliderActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", position);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    favImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SliderActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", position);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return gridView;
}
}
```

Try this